# Continuity of a probability integral

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $m: \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow [0,1] $ be a probability measure *without point masses*.

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be (*jointly*) *continuous*.

Define the mapping $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow [0,1]$ as
$$ \varphi(x) \ := \ m\left( \left\{ v \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid f(v,x)>0\right\} \right) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \mathbb{1}_{ \{ v \mid f(v,x) > 0 \} }(v) \ m(dv) . $$

Questions.

1. Is $\varphi$ continuous?
2. Is $\varphi$ continuous, if we assume $f$ disjointly continuous (i.e. $\forall v $, $f(v,\cdot)$ is continuous and $\forall x$, $f(\cdot,x)$ is continuous)?

Comment: Just a note: $m$ not having point masses **does not** imply that $m$ has a density. That is, there are continuous functions which are not absolutely continuous.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let's just assume that there are no point masses.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering if the following is a counterexample: $f(v,x) = vx$, with dimensions $n = m = 1$.

Then $\varphi(0) = 0$; while for all $\epsilon>0$, $\varphi(\epsilon) = m( \mathbb{R}_{>0} )$, which may be strictly positive.